# Std::cout function as parameter

Tags: c++, cout

I recently noticed you can do stuff like

```
void foo(){ }
//...
std::cout<<foo<<std::endl;
```

This tends to print out "1", regardless of the passed function.

Now I'm curious: What exactly is this doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`foo` is *decaying* to a function pointer, which is then converted to a boolean with value true (because the function pointer is not null), which is printed as "1", because booleans are printed as numbers by default.

Try this:

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha << foo << std::endl;
```

Comment: Is it "decaying" or is it implicitly converted to a boolean?

Comment: The function reference `foo` decays to a pointer, which is then implicitly converted.

Comment: why is it a boolean? my compiler (VS2010) printed directly the adress.

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie I have no idea what your compiler might be doing.

Comment: Can you provide a reference? I thought only arrays decay to pointers.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore see duplicate question

Comment: @SebastianRedl okay, then explain why it should be converted to a boolean?

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie Because the std::ostream::operator<<(bool) overload is the best available. If you look at all the overloads there are (and there are **lots**) and do the overload resolution yourself, you'll find that no other overload even fits.

Comment: @Borgleader I don't find `decay` anywhere in that question.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I thought the first answer was what you were looking for. My bad.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore From C++11 5p8: "Whenever a glvalue expression appears as an operand of an operator that expects a prvalue for that operand, the lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, or function-to-pointer standard conversions are applied to convert the expression to a prvalue." This is generally referred to as "decay", as evidenced by the `std::decay` type trait described in C++ 20.9.7.6. Other parts of the standard describe the same transformations for other contexts, such as arguments to function calls where no lvalue is needed.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I don't follow how "std::decay type trait described in C++ 20.9.7.6" is evidence for how this is generally referred to as "decaying".

Comment: @LuchianGrigore The word "decay" doesn't appear in C++03. However, the array-to-pointer and function-to-pointer conversions were called "decaying" in the C and C++ communities already when I started learning C++ (12 years ago), and probably long before that. This is why the type trait that performs the equivalent type transformations is called "decay". Or in reverse, the fact that a "decay" trait was added to C++ that does the transformations of those two conversions is evidence that those conversions are referred to as "decay".

Comment: Hmmm, interesting, good to know. Any other situations that are referred to as "decay"? (other than array to pointer & function to pointer)

Comment: Well, the decay trait also does on the type level what the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion does, i.e. drop references and top-level cv qualifiers. But that wasn't usually referred to as "decaying" AFAIK.